# Parse string from array to use in csv

Tags: php, csv

Im generating a array that record looks like :

```
315 => 
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Bangkok ICD' (length=11)
  1 => string '[pc_315]' (length=8)
  2 => string '45.00;5600.00;677.78;45.00;454.00;;;;'
```

Next im putting this array in csv using simple mathod:

```
private function fill_file_data($list)
{
    $file = $this->csv_file_path."/tariff_{$this->freight_tariff->id}_matrix.csv";
    if(!file_exists($file))
    {
        file_put_contents($file, "");
    }
    $file_handler = fopen($file, 'w');
    foreach($list as $fields)
    {
        fputcsv($file_handler, $fields, $this->delimiter, $this->separator);
    }
    fclose($file_handler);
    return;
}
```

But there is a problem with this part :
2 => string '45.00;5600.00;677.78;45.00;454.00;;;;'

I it is separeted by semicolon but fputcsv treats this as a string. Is there a way to read this part as csv collumns?

Comment: So explode string with these values by `;` and add to csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should `explode` your string by `;` and add this values as new array elements, for example

```
$arr = array(
    'Bangkok ICD',
    '[pc_315]',
    '45.00;5600.00;677.78;45.00;454.00;;;;'
);
$new_values = explode(';', $arr[2]);
// now we remove string '45.00;5600.00;677.78;45.00;454.00;;;;'
unset($arr[2]);
$arr = array_merge($arr, $new_values);
```

After that you can pass this item to your method.